# Screen Space Reflections isn't showing in the final render using EEVEE in Blender 2.80

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

This questions has been asked before, but the solution didn't work for me.

I have a **Metallic 1.0** object on a **Roughness 1.0** plane with one point light and HDRI. When I switch to render mode, I can see the Screen Space Reflections in the Viewport. But when I render the image, there is no Screen Space Reflections.

The sampling of both Render and Viewport is **16**. Following are the Viewport and Rendered images.

[image: Viewport]

[image: Rendered]